# Fill a table with an array

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel

I have an array of this kind:

```
$arr = [['checkTitle' => 'Проверка наличия файла robots.txt', "result" => "true",
            'stateTitle' => 'Состоние',   'recommendTitle' => "Рекомендации",
            'stateResult' => "Файл есть", 'recommendResult' => "Нету"],];
```

And a table like this:

[image: And such a table]

I try to fill the table using the following code:

```
foreach ( $this->createArray() as $key => $item ) {
    $currentColumn = 0;
    $this->sheet->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($currentColumn, $startLine, $key + 1);

    $this->sheet->getStyle("A2")->applyFromArray($this->textAlignCenter());

    $this->document->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells("A" . $startLine . ":" . "A" . ($startLine + 1));
    $this->document->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells("B" . $startLine . ":" . "B" . ($startLine + 1));
    $this->document->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells("C" . $startLine . ":" . "C" . ($startLine + 1));

    foreach ( $item as $value ) {
        $this->sheet->getStyle("A")->applyFromArray($this->textAlignCenter());
        $currentColumn++;
        $this->sheet->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($currentColumn, $startLine, $value);
    }
    $startLine += 3;
}
```

But this does not work and i rewrote the array in another way:

```
$arr = ['checkTitle' => 'Проверка наличия файла robots.txt', "status" => "true",
            'info' => ['title' => "Файл есть", "Рекомендации" => "Нету"]],];
```

However, this did not work either.

How can i fill the table correctly with this array?

Comment: I'm afraid you'll have to post full class code to get some help. it LOOKS like PHPExcel, but I'm not 100% sure if that's what you're after.

Comment: @janmyszkier but there is nothing else in my class :c only styles

Comment: Welcome @Racoon, what happens when you run the code? What doesn't work? Is there an error?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't use PHPExcel which I think you are using BUT I did with:
https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/develop/#getting-started

and if you install that library with composer the way their docs say and then place this in your index.php :

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx;

class test
{

    /* @var Xlsx\Worksheet $sheet */
    public $sheet;
    function createArray()
    {
        $arr = [
            [
            'checkTitle' => 'Проверка наличия файла robots.txt',
            "result" => "true",
            'stateTitle' => 'Состоние',
            'recommendTitle' => "Рекомендации",
            'stateResult' => "Файл есть",
            'recommendResult' => "Нету"
            ]
        ];

        return $arr;
    }

    function createTable()
    {
        $spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();
        /* @var \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet\Worksheet $activeSheet */
        $activeSheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
        $this->sheet = $activeSheet;

        /*Header*/
        $this->sheet->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(1, 1, 'No');
        $this->sheet->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(2, 1, 'checkTitle');
        $this->sheet->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(3, 1, 'stateTitle');
        $this->sheet->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(4, 1, '---');
        $this->sheet->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(5, 1, 'fifth header');

        /*Actual Lines from your array */
        $startLine = 2;
        foreach ($this->createArray() as $key => $item) {
            $currentColumn = 0;
            $this->sheet->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($currentColumn, $startLine, $key);

            $currentColumn = 1;
            $this->sheet->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($currentColumn, $startLine, $key + 1);

            $this->sheet->mergeCells("A" . $startLine . ":" . "A" . ($startLine + 1));
            $this->sheet->mergeCells("B" . $startLine . ":" . "B" . ($startLine + 1));
            $this->sheet->mergeCells("C" . $startLine . ":" . "C" . ($startLine + 1));

            foreach ($item as $value) {
                $currentColumn++;
                var_dump('setting '. $value.' to '.$currentColumn.'.'.$startLine);
                $this->sheet->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($currentColumn, $startLine, $value);
            }

            $startLine += 3;
        }
        $writer = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xls($spreadsheet);
        $writer->save('hello world.xlsx');
    }
}

$table = new test();
$table->createTable();
```

you will get something close to what you requested, but no styling. While this doesn't solve your problem 100%, it is good starting point for you to solve your issue.

OH, and one note: please using english in your code and images, not all people know your language, english was used to create programming languages for a reason, please use it when refrering programming questions to raise your changes of getting an answer ;)